# Does Anyone Have idea about Stream?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365-developer, microsoft-graph, microsoft-teams

Does anyone have idea about Microsoft stream?
Can we use RestApi in Stream and Display all the videos in On-premise?

Answer (score 2):

As of today, there is provision for using Stream videos only in SharePoint Online. Link - [Microsoft Stream webpart for SharePoint Online](https://stream.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/bring-stream-videos-to-sharepoint-pages-and-yammer-conversations/)

But, we can expect Microsoft to release their administrative controls soon in Steam, so that we can leverage REST API and use the videos in SharePoint onpremises. The transition from [Office 365 videos entirely into MS Stream](https://stream.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/stream-o365video-feature-breakdown/) is already on its way.